# How do i split a String into an array with split and regex?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

The string that I am trying to split is the following:

```
#1 Single" (2006)\t\t\t\t\t2006-????
```

The regex i am trying is:

```
(["#0-9 a-zA-Z]*\w") (\([0-9]*\w\)).*([0-9{4}]*\d-[\?0-9{4}]*)
```

This however takes the whole string and not parts.
How do i make it into an array?

```
array("\"#1 Single\"", "2006", "2006-????");
```

Comment: What should `array()` be and why don't you use the `split()` method? If the structure of the string is too complex for "simple" split try `Pattern` and `Matcher` along with the `group()` methods and simple array/collection operations.

Comment: As Thomas said, use the `group` property of the `Matcher` to get the values of the individual matched groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already grouping in the regex the different parts you're interested in, so you should retrieve them separately and use them to populate the resulting array :

```
//assumes a Matcher matcher which has already matched the text with .find() or .matches()
int groupCount = 3;  // for more complex cases, use matcher.groupCount();
String[] parts = new String[groupCount];
for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < groupCount; groupIndex++) {
    parts[groupIndex] = matcher.group(groupIndex);
}
```